# How to unhide navigation bar on swipe in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller.  In the NC, I have selected the option Hide Bars On Swipe.  Upon scrolling down in the VC, the Nav Bar hides as it should, but does not reappear upon scrolling up.  Is this behavior by design?  How can I hide/unhide when scrolling?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what kind of scrollview are you using, a UITableView, UICollectionView or just UIScrollView?

Comment: @LuisMejías I have a ViewController containing a UITableView.

Comment: Remember that to get that behavior working properly the UITableView has to be only full screen size.

Comment: @LuisMejías The top of my TableView was constrained to the top layout guide.  I expanded the Table to take up the entire View Controller and now the NavBar is working properly as you suggested.  However, my first cell is cut of by the NavBar.  Could you please advise?  Thanks!

Comment: Check your view controller attributes inspector in IB. Look for "Extend Edges" option under View Controller, and uncheck "Under Top Bars" if it is checked.